# Retrieve tag of every post in a hashtag instagram

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I need a very simple Instagram API to retrieve every username that posted something on a specific hashtag, i tried with Instaloader and BeautifulSoup but I didn't realise anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram provides a Hashtag API for this usecase

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/